# How can I set an icon to qinputdialog in pyqt4?

Tags: python, modal-dialog, pyqt4

here I have the following code:

```
languages = ['English', 'rus', 'uk', 'fr', 'germ']   
s, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(window, 'title', 'help', languages, current = 0, editable = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it should use the window icon set on it's parent

```
window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('/path/to/icon.png'))

languages = ['English', 'rus', 'uk', 'fr', 'germ']   
s, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(window, 'title', 'help', languages, current = 0, editable = False)
```

Comment: well, I created this dialog window before I set the main window's icon, thank you!